# cannot read the property of "db" of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am learning **Nodejs**, but now I am getting this 
**[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtqW0.png)**

there is no more code accept this:

```
let express = require('express')
let mongodb = require('mongodb')
let server =  express()
let db

let connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://admin:******@cluster0-1vj27.mongodb.net/TodoApp?retryWrites=true'
mongodb.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client) {
  db = client.db("TodoApp")
  server.listen(3000)
})

server.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

server.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.send(`....`)
})
server.post('/create-item', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('items').insertOne({text: req.body.item}, function() {
      res.send("Thank you submitting the form.")
    })
})
```

I am new to **node**, please help I am stuck.
What should I do now please help

Comment: Can you try this : replace `let mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;` also before `db = client.db("TodoApp")`, you need to check for error like `if(err) console.error(err)`, in general rather than logging you need to do something overthere..

Comment: what error are you getting now ?

Comment: insertOne not defind

Answer (score 1):

You must use `mongodb.MongoClient`, not `mongodb` directly :

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// connect
```

Find an example here : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html

Also, you should check if there is an error before trying to access `client` :

```js
mongoClient.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(error);
    return;
  }
  db = client.db("TodoApp")
  server.listen(3000)
})
```